# Rejected - TRUSTmanager (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Tags: email, email-server, ip, spam, blacklist

After changing an IP address of email server (Postfix stack) I've found host that denies email message with:

```
hostname postfix/smtp[38212]: 1AF542406D0: to=<user.name@domain.tld>, relay=xxx.xxx.xxx[public-ip-of-server]:25, delay=0.8, delays=0.09/0/0.63/0.08, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host xxx.xxx.xxx[public-ip-of-server] said: 550 5.7.1 <sender.username@senderdomain.tld>... Rejected - TRUSTmanager (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

This (crucial) part is odd:

```
said: 550 5.7.1 <sender.username@senderdomain.tld>... Rejected - TRUSTmanager (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

Usually ESP giants (like Google, Microsoft, Yahoo) are placing here additional info about reasons for rejecting - and even if they don't you know (or you might find out easily) where to go from there.

It is important to stress that new IP address is **not blacklisted** and that before IP change there were regular email traffic between two servers.

This **`TRUSTmanager`** has very few resources that might be find just with googling.

Does anyone know is this any kind of blacklist on which administrators may request removal and how to do it? Or any other useful resource on subject how to fix this problem.

---

EDIT (12.12.2017)

This `TRUSTmanager` is a component of some `Clearswift Email Gateway / Clearswift Secure Email Gateway` email security software, not sure what kind exactly, and does not operate by (or, at least not solely by) local settings.

So, this software has **some kind of centralized black list** and contacting administrator of other email server, although may solve specific case by manual whitelisting IP address  is not good enough option. Now, the question is, how to get out of this list?

Comment: Contact the administrator of the other mail server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks. But how exactly? To send email to postmaster@ fqdn of server or some hosted domain hoping I shall find him? And is there some kind of standardized procedure or form of communication for this?

Comment: Postmaster is standard. You could also look up the domain's whois record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one answered:

[Clearswift Secure Email Gateway](https://www.clearswift.com/products/email-security-products) is an email security software and they are in charge of their internal blacklist and the 'world outside' does not know on basis of what criteria this blacklist is established and maintained.

So, if you got new IP address which gets rejected with error message posted above you have option to [contact](https://www.clearswift.com/contact-us) and ask them to remove your IP address from their blacklist.

---

Needless to say, you shouldn't hope for positive answer from any blacklist vendor unless you made sure that all standard conditions they may request from you are fulfilled:

- (obviously) not sending spam,
- having proper DNS and reverse DNS setup,
- not being an open relay

...and such. Good luck.